# How to enable root login and password authentication trough recovery web console DigitalOcean?

Tags: ssh, centos, cpanel, digital-ocean, recovery

Yesterday, I update my cPanel version on my droplet. After update, it says that I have to enable cpHulk. So, I enable it, with a bunch of config that I don't event understand. The thing that I remember that I disabled root login trough WHM and SSH. I don't have any other login except root for WHM and SSH.

I did some tutorial that I found:

1. I reset the root password at DigitalOcean dashboard, and I try to login SSH which is not working.
2. I reset password and login to WHM, also not working.
3. I tried to boot from recovery ISO and enable SSH root login, also not working.

And my question: How to enable root login and password authentication trough recovery web console?

Comment: so, you're locked out of the droplet (I understand that when you disabled root login access you didn't set up a SSL certificate that allows you to log-in without providing username/password credentials)? If that's the case, I believe your only two ways around this are getting DO support to help you or destroying the droplet and starting from scratch (not from a backup image)... it sucks, but I think the nuclear option will be faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done.

In the control panel, I click Recovery on the left, then click the Boot from Recovery ISO box.
I toggle the power button to power your Droplet back on. When it’s on, I access my Droplet by clicking on Access to the left, then clicking the Launch Console button.

This Linux environment is running from the ISO image, not from my Droplet, so I will have to mount the filesystem into my environment in order to access my files. To do so, select 1 at the recovery menu and press ENTER. My disk image will be detected and mounted under /mnt in the recovery environment.

Then I go to the bash by select menu 6, and ENTER

Then I update the ssh config:

```html
cd /mnt
nano etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

I added a line in the Authentication section of the file that says PermitRootLogin yes. This line may already exist and be commented out with a "#". In this case, remove the "#".

```html
# Authentication:
#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10
```

Then I save the updated `etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

Back to the control panel. Go to recovery and select "Boot from Hard Drive". I turn off and on the server.

I try to login trough SSH using root, and it works. Then I continue to disable cpHulk. https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/cPHulk+Management+on+the+Command+Line#cPHulkManagementontheCommandLine-DisablecPHulk